# Carefully mending "Objects are not aligned" error in python, with matrices

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

In my recent exercise, I were to write a function that get a matrix A and a number k, and gives the k-th approximation to A's eigenvalues, using the approximation formulas of Rayleigh Quotient Iteration. I wrote the following function, made sure the first iteration is okay, but then the second get as error, and I don't know how to maintain a matrix or a vector the way there are. I am frustrated and would really appreciate any kind of help.

```
def RayleighQuotientItreation(A,k):
   import math
   import numpy as np
   I=np.matrix(np.identity(A.shape[0]))
   b=np.random.rand(A.shape[0])
   b=math.pow(normal(b),-1)*b
   u=(np.dot(b,(np.dot(A.T,b)).T))[0,0]
   for i in range(0,k):
      b, u=(np.dot(np.linalg.inv((A-  u*I)).T,b))*math.pow(normal((np.dot(np.linalg.inv((A-u*I)),b)).T),-1), (np.dot((np.dot(b.T,A)),b))[0,0]
   return u
```

Comment: It is under control now. How do I lock a question?